STOL AIRCRAFT in Flight
Aviators here is a question. Can you land a "STOL" aircraft in a "C5A Galaxy" while both are flying?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Have you looked into how wide the C-5 cargo bay isn't, in the context of "aircraft".

I was rather hoping for a treadmill spinning on the floor of the Galaxy...

Not saying such a thing would be totally impossible, but nope.
Look up the width of the cargo bay of a C5, then look up the wingspan of your favorite STOL plane that you had in mind for this question.
Then look up the approach speed of a C5 and the cruise speed of your subject STOL plane.
There may be other issues making such an attempt highly unfeasible, but those two things would be the main ones to consider, and would rule out any serious consideration.

Not to mention, enjoying the wake turbulence you'd get, flying along closer & closer behind an aircraft that outweighs yours by a couple orders of magnitude... doesn't seem like fun.
